# How to slice last N data Django

Tags: python, django

For example I have 5 row with data in my db and when I want to show first 3 row in my html,
I'm using `for` loop with `slice` like `{% for x in y|slice:":3" %}`. But now my question is how to show last 3 row from db.

Comment: `for x in y|slice:"-3:"`

Comment: you can order by descending id's and follow the same procedure..

Comment: Please do not do that in the template. Slice in the view. The content of the response should be determined by the view. Rendering it in a stylish form is the task of the template.

Comment: @M3duZa: this is a template tag. You can slice in the view with `myqueryset[-3:]`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would really advice you *not* to slice querysets in a template, but in the view. Normally a view decides *what* to show in the response, and a template decide *how* to show that in the response.

You can slice a queryset in the response with `[-3:]`. So if your view has a queryset:

```
SomeModel.objects.all()
```

you can slice the queryset with:

```
SomeModel.objects.all().reverse()[:3]
```

Comment: @Willem Van Onsem This `SomeModel.objects.all()[-3:]` will raise `AssertionError: Negative indexing is not supported. `, isn't? At least in Django 2.x

Comment: @funnydman: fair point. The documentation advices to use `reverse()`: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/